# Xcode provisioning profiles show nothing after click create

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I clicked the create in on action. Just like show. Then, the create button disappear, but nothing shows up. Tried restart xcode and reboot mac, it still shows none of the provisioning profiles not showing anything. Anyone know how I can I download the ios development provisioning profiles? I check it on developer website, there is no option relate to provisioning profiles

[image]

Comment: Control + Click on a Signing Identity and try clicking "export"...

Comment: @l'L'l can you tell me why this happened? I download the certification, but it is not working. I need provisioning profiles on ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles , but there is no MobileDevice folder on my library folder. I try manually create a MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles, and put downloaded certification on this folder, but it is not working at all. error like  "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities. " Is there any way i can automatically installing provisioning profiles ?

Comment: In the Project Navigator click on your project ( the first file in the list ), and then in the main window select "General". What do you see under "Signing"?

Comment: Do you have a free Apple Developer account? Also, have you actually built the app? I don't believe Xcode created the provisioning profile until you build the app to a device for the first time. You can check that the signing identity was created by looking for certificates in your keychain.